# moment js timeformat not producing the correct time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an API returning a date as follows:

2020-04-30T14:52:07.123

and I am trying to format it as follows:

```js
$('.dateTime').text(moment(new Date("2020-04-30T14:52:07.123")).format("DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss A"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>


<span class="dateTime"></span>
```

but I am not getting the right result. I get this:

`"30-04-2020 00:00:00 AM"`

Day, month and year are correct but the the hour, minutes and seconds are set to midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `00:00:00` is a side effect of new features included in moment 2.25.x version, if you run you code using previous version (e.g. 2.24.0), you will get `30-04-yyyy 14:52:07 AM`.

The main issue with your code is that moment tokens are case sensitive (see [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)), so you have to use uppercase `YYYY` to display 4 digit year instead of lowercase `yyyyy`.

Moreover, since your input string is in ISO 8601 recognized format you can directly use [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and remove `new Date()`.

Working example:

```js
$('.dateTime').text(moment("2020-04-30T14:52:07.123").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss A"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment.js"></script>

<span class="dateTime"></span>
```

Comment: Looks like I was using moment-with-locales.min.js, switched to 2.25.3 and I had to change year to uppercase YYYY